# What is the X desktop start up process / program hierarchy?

Tags: desktop

How do all the components that make up an "X desktop session" fit together?

I've gone through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System , and I see that there are all sorts of components like X Servers, Login Managers, Session Managers, Window Managers, Desktop Environments, ...

But, I'm not clear on how they all fit together.

One reason I'm trying to figure this out so that I can insert my own logic into the boot process such that in certain cases, the system will directly boot to a particular user's desktop session, rather than a login greeter.

But, I'm also just trying to understand the architectural design, so that I can extend this to Xvnc style setups as well.

Thank you

Comment: What is a Xvnc style setup?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. The dependencies changed in time. It also depends on whether you use KDE or GNOME. While trying to answer your question I just used `pstree` while my GUI is running (in my case: KDE on CentOS).

There it seems that GDM starts the X-Server and KDE. After that KINIT kicks in.

So GDM is propably the place where you want to kick in.

Answer (score 1):

First process is display manager (DM), which launches X server and shows login prompt to user. After successful authentication in launches DE's session manager, which launches all other parts (WM and so). Most DMs can be configured to launch specified user's session automatically.